# Dev-C++ gives '&' reference syntax error

Tags: c, dev-c++

What's the matter with Dev-C++, or are there errors in my code about using reference variable?

```
#include <stdio.h>

    struct P {
        int x;  
    };

    int main(int argc, char **argv){
        struct P Point[5];
        struct P & rPoint;

        int i;
        for(i=0;i<=4;i++) {
            rPoint = Point[i]; // I know. I can use Point[i].x = i. But...
            rPoint.x = i;
        }

        for(i=0;i<=4;i++) {
            rPoint = Point[i];
            printf("%d\n", rPoint.x);
        }
       system("pause");
       return 0;
    }
```

**Error:** 9 C:***\main.c syntax error before '&' token

Comment: I don't think there are Dev-C++ specific libraries, what matters is the compiler, and with Dev-C++ you usually use just an oldish version of MinGW (which is the same compiler usually used in other free - and better - IDEs).

Comment: $ gcc test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:9:20: error: ‘rPoint’ declared as reference but not initialized
test.cpp:21:22: error: ‘system’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: I couldn't build the library on mingw. The library is coming a pack on Dev-C++. A bit sloth :)

Comment: AFAIK Dev-C++ is just a IDE, the compiler behind is gcc and there are no special non-standard libraries bundled with Dev-C++ (but maybe I am wrong). Anyway, that's a mix of C and C++, I would say it is plain C, with a feature of C++ used, but nothing seriously C++ish; I have the strong belief that the use of `system("pause")` is a bad and evil programming habit, even for windows programmers...

Comment: have you any of devpaks libraries? anyway you don't need a specific IDE to use precompiled dynamic or static libs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ does not allow unassigned references, so this is your error:

```
struct P & rPoint;
```

If you want reassignment, use a pointer.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct P points[5];
    struct P* point;

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++) {
        point = points + i; // or &points[i]
        point->x = i;
    }
    // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ references don't work like that.  You have to initialize the reference when you define it.  So something like:

```
int x = 5;
int &r = x;   // Initialise r to refer to x
```

Also, you can't "re-seat" a reference; it will always refer to the same variable.  So continuing the above example:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;
int &r = x;

r = y;  // This will not re-seat y; it's equivalent to x = y
```

Answer (score 2):

> Error: 9 C:***\main**.c** syntax error before '&' token

Besides what the others said, you are compiling it as a C file, and in C references do not exist. Give it a .cpp extension if you want to compile it as C++, or make `point` a pointer instead of a reference (actually, you'll have to make it a pointer anyway, since you can't reseat a reference).